# Rebind a live() click event after using die()?

Tags: jquery, bind, live, unbind, die

I haven't been able to solve my problem searching through Stack. I have my live() function below. You can see how I want to stop the button being clicked a second time while the function is running, and then rebind. The button dies unbind, but it doesn't bind again... :S

```
$('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click',function(){

    var firstSlide = $('.slider li:first-child');

    if(firstSlide.attr('class') != 'active'){   
        $('.control-left, .prevActive').die('click');   
        moveSlider('left');
        $('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click');
    }

});
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+ then you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in place of `live()` or `delegate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to unbind and rebind just use a flag:

```
var running = false;
$('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click',function(){
    var firstSlide = $('.slider li:first-child');

    if(firstSlide.attr('class') != 'active' && !running){ 
        running = true;
        moveSlider('left');
        running = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat! I see where I was going wrong - quite a silly mistake really :)

Answer (score 1):

Your last line of code does not bind anything to the click handler. You must bind a function

```
$('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click', function () { code here });
```

In your situation you would probably want to do something like this

```
var myspecialclickfunction = function(){

  var firstSlide = $('.slider li:first-child');

  if(firstSlide.attr('class') != 'active'){   
      $('.control-left, .prevActive').die('click');   
      moveSlider('left');
      $('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click', myspecialclickfunction);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click',myspecialclickfunction);
});
```

---

Also jQuery 1.42 to 1.6x you should be using

- [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for binding to future elements
- [undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) for unbinding to for delegated events

in jquery 1.7+

- [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), and [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) have been combined in the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/), [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) have been combined in the [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
- in addition there has been the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) added that will allow a bound event to run only once.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any function to .live.. try this:

```
$('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click',function hello(){

    var firstSlide = $('.slider li:first-child');

    if(firstSlide.attr('class') != 'active'){   
        $('.control-left, .prevActive').die('click');   
        moveSlider('left');
        $('.control-left, .prevActive').live('click', hello);
    }

});
```